# How to translate meta titles? Angular Internationalization (i18n) with AOT

Tags: angular, internationalization, meta

How can I translate and set the meta title/page title that are using Angular Internationalization (i18n) with AOT. I can't seem to find anything on the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#!#translate-attributes).

Comment: with Angular 9 you could do it like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61006883/3160597

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You might want to check out this module **[ngx-meta](https://github.com/fulls1z3/ngx-meta/tree/master/packages/@ngx-meta/core)**. Once runtime i18n will be available (in Angular 6, announced for march 2018) the angular team will work on i18n translation outside templates ([#11405](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11405)).
Combining both you'll be able to dynamically change meta!

**EDIT END**

There is a GitHub issue [#8947](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8947)

> xi18n should parse index.html and build should fill in the translated texts in index.html

As ocombe wrote it's not possible yet to translate strings inside the index.html since it is no template. But its on the [roadmap](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8947#issuecomment-353364471) of [Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io/)

> it will be possible as part of universal (it's on the roadmap)

For now you can only use a third party solution like ngx-tranlsate or if it's not urgent wait for the implementation of this feature.